# C Using strcmp to check a URL path

Tags: c

I am trying to see if a string equates to a URL path. It should be simple, but the strcmp is always returning < 0 (-47). I'm probably doing something wrong with the slashes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    char path[9];
    strcpy(path, "/my/path/");
    int len = strlen(path);

    char lastChar[1];
    strcpy(lastChar, &path[len - 1]);
    printf("LAST CHAR SET TO %s\n", lastChar);

    bool isPageRequest = strcmp(lastChar, "/") == 0;
    if(isPageRequest)
    {
        printf("ITS A PAGE REQUEST\n");
    }

    bool isMyPath = strcmp(path, "/my/path/") == 0;
    if(isMyPath)
    {
        printf("ITS MY PATH PAGE\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am expecting `ITS MY PATH PAGE` to print out.. but it does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array into which you copy the last slash is too short: `char lastChar[1];` It should have a size of at least 2 to receive a null terminator.

You do not actually need an array for this, just comparing the last character with `'/'` can be done directly.

You have the same bug for `path`, it is too short for `"/my/path/"`.

Copying beyond the end of an array has undefined behavior, which means anything can happen, including, by coincidence, the behavior you actually expect.

Try this modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void) {
    char path[] = "/my/path/";
    int len = strlen(path);
    char lastChar = path[len - 1];

    printf("LAST CHAR SET TO %c\n", lastChar);

    bool isPageRequest = lastChar == '/';
    if (isPageRequest) {
        printf("IT'S A PAGE REQUEST\n");
    }

    bool isMyPath = strcmp(path, "/my/path/") == 0;
    if (isMyPath) {
        printf("IT'S MY PATH PAGE\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I understand this. What I don't understand is why that made the rest of the code work..

Comment: @JDoe.: undefined behavior is perverse, it may make you think you fixed a bug, and then make you wonder how?